# Parent - Child sql query

Tags: sql, hierarchical

```
id  parent_id
1   0
2   0
3   2
4   0
5   1
6   0
```

I need a query that will return parent rows (parent_id=0) followed by its child rows:

1. first parent
2. all children of first parent
3. second parent
4. all children of second parent
5. third parent
6. fourth parent

Expected result: ordered by id

```
id   parent_id
-------------------------------------------
1    0 (first parent)
5    1     (all children of first parent)
2    0 second parent
3    2     (all children of second parent)
4    0 third parent
6    0 fourth parent
```

I can use union of parents followed by all childs
But that gives me parents first then the children.
I need parent and immediately its children.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using two temp tables and three variables.

```
CREATE TABLE #Parents
(
RowId bigint identity(1,1),
Id    bigint
)
```

CREATE TABLE #Results
(
RowId    bigint identity(1,1),
Id       bigint,
ParentId bigint
)

DECLARE @Count1   bigint
DECLARE @Count2   bigint
DECLARE @ParentId bigint

INSERT INTO #Parents
SELECT Id 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ParentId = 0
ORDER BY Id

SET @Count1 = 0
SELECT @Count2 = MAX(RowId) FROM #Parents

WHILE @Count1 < @Count2
BEGIN
  SET @Count1 = @Count1 +1
  SELECT @ParentId = Id FROM #Parents WHERE RowId = @Count1
  INSERT INTO #Results (Id, ParentId) VALUES (@Count1, 0)
  INSERT INTO #Results (Id, ParentId) 
  SELECT ID, ParentId 
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ID = @Count1
  ORDER BY Id
END

SELECT
Id,
ParentId
FROM #Results
ORDER BY RowId

DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #Parents

Answer (score 3):

If you're in SQL Server 2005+, you can use a recursive CTE, making sure that you maintain a field that you can order by at the end.

Try this:

```
declare @t table (id int, parent_id int)
insert @t
select 1,0
union all select 2,0
union all select 3,2
union all select 4,0
union all select 5,1
union all select 6,0
;

with tree as (
select t.*, convert(varbinary(max),t.id) as ordered
from @t t
where parent_id = 0
union all
select t.*, ordered + convert(varbinary(max),t.id)
from tree base
 join
 @t t
 on t.parent_id = base.id
 )
select * 
from tree
order by ordered
;
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my sample table
Can you write the query that gives the output I specified above as my expected result?
Thanks

Comment: I mean CTE gives me all the parent rows first. Then all the children.

Not first parent then its children, followed by second parent and its children and so on

Comment: I am exactly looking for result used to display this post and its comments. 

Parent comment and then its replies (children) then another comment and its replies. The replies are the children on parent comment.

Comment: The key to this problem is the column used for ordering. I'm sure my query works, just substitute @t for the table you have.

Comment: Simple union gives me the result I want after tweaking the query little bit. I think the order by column is the key

Comment: Ok. I'm still unclear why you say my query is wrong. I produce a field to put them in the order you need. Also, my query handles multiple levels. Can you post your answer sone time?