# Sql question: Getting Parent rows followed by child rows

Tags: sql, hierarchical

id  parent_id

1     0

2     0

3     2

4     0

5     1

6     0

I need a query that will return parent rows (parent_id=0) followed by its child rows

first parent

all children of first parent

second parent

all children of second parent

third parent

fourth parent

Expected result: ordered by id

id   parent_id

1    0 (first parent)

5    1     (all children of first parent)

2    0 second parent

3    2     (all children of second parent)

4    0 third parent

6    0 fourth parent

I can use union of parents followed by all childs
But that gives me parents first then the children.
I need parent and immediately its children.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604463/parent-child-sql-query

Comment: @Projapati, why the same question twice?

Comment: The first ones seems had wrong format. Didn't know how to delete.
Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use a recursive CTE for this:

```
WITH r AS 
 (SELECT id, 
    NULL AS parent_id, 
    CAST(right('000' + CAST(row_number() 
         OVER (table.id) AS varchar), 3) AS varchar(50))
  FROM table WHERE parent IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT table.id, table.parent_id, 
    CAST(r.ord + right('000' + CAST(row_number() 
         OVER (ORDER BY table.id) AS varchar), 3) AS varchar(50))
  FROM r JOIN table 
   ON table.parent = r.id)

 SELECT id 
 FROM r
 ORDER BY left(ord + '000000000000000000000000000000000', 36)
```

Note that this particular version will break if any ID has a value greater than 999, and it will break if you have more than 12 levels. If this is a concern to you, you need to adjust the number of zeroes in the various places.

There might be better ways, but this one works.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example solution using a union with an order by clause (It wont work for deep nesting though).

```
SELECT  p.id, 
        p.parent_id, 
        p.name,  
        p.id AS sequence
FROM topics AS p 
WHERE p.parent_id = 0
UNION 
SELECT  t.id, 
        t.parent_id, 
        t.name, 
        t.parent_id AS sequence
FROM topics AS t
WHERE t.parent_id <> 0
ORDER BY sequence, parent_id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't do this with a single SQL statement if all you're storing is the parent id.  If you need to retrieve the tree of data quickly, you'll have to consider storing a pre-order traversal.  It's easier than it sounds and it's very well described here: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database

Comment: You are totally wrong on this one. I just made a little change to the column I use to sort the result after union. I have the exact result I need. It is much simpler than I thought. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: any chance you'd be willing to post your solution?  just in case someone in future has the same problem..  thanks.