# How can i order my recursive select in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql question: Getting Parent rows followed by child rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604537/sql-question-getting-parent-rows-followed-by-child-rows)

I need to "order by" a recursive result by level. Then, I will make it like this structure:

```
Level   | ID    | Name       | Parent
=======================================
1       | 10    | **Rich**   |   
2       | 11    | Sony       | **Rich** 
1       | 13    | Mary       |
1       | 15    | **John**   |
2       | 12    | Lily       | **John**
```

It must be ordered as such, like tree structure: first element - parent then child.

Comment: Your table has 4 fields, and some records only have 3 values.  If you highlight your table and click `{}` it will make it a code snippet and be evenly spaced (readable).  Also, do you ever have more than 2 levels?  and could you give examples of both the input data and the desired output format/order.

Comment: Looks like someone hasn't understood their homework...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
... ORDER BY CONCAT(IFNULL(parent,''),name)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the  [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function if you are using sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursing, ordering example in T-SQL.

```
declare @table table(
    [level] int,
    id int,
    [name] nvarchar(32),
    [parent] nvarchar(32)
);
insert into @table([level], id, [name], parent) values(1, 10, '**Rich**', null);
insert into @table([level], id, [name], parent) values(2, 11, 'Sony', '**Rich**' );
insert into @table([level], id, [name], parent) values(1, 13, 'Mary', null);
insert into @table([level], id, [name], parent) values(1, 15, '**John**', null);
insert into @table([level], id, [name], parent) values(2, 12, 'Lily', '**John**');

with rec ([level], id, [name], parent, seq) as (
    select
            t.[level],
            t.id,
            t.[name],
            t.[parent],
            cast(t.[level] as varbinary(max)) as seq
        from
            @table as t
        where
            t.parent is null
    union all select
            t.[level],
            t.id,
            t.[name],
            t.[parent],
            r.seq + cast(t.[level] as varbinary(max)) as seq
        from
            rec as r
            inner join @table as t
                on t.parent = r.name
)
select
        *
    from
        rec
    order by
        seq asc
;
```

The key points here are (1) recursion via `with` and (2) concatenating a binary representation of the level number into a single sequence indicator.